# NFS server with more secure export control

Tags: nfs, kerberos

Is it possible to restrict access to a NFS server to machines based on some kind of key, password or token, instead on just an IP address?

I would like to exports a /home folder with user files to several other machines. An IP address based access list works, but not great security.

I have seen Kerberos based NFS infrastructure, but the problem is that a user on a NFS client has to authenticate first to access his data in /home - which means that the user cannot login via ssh using his private key. User web pages in home folders do not work. Also if the user stays logged in for a longer period, the Kerberos token will expire and access to users' files is lost.

Is there another way of exporting NFS that would not have these limitations but it will not give access to data to anyone having a certain IP address?

Comment: Re: The "user cannot login via ssh using his private key" - if you are using a solution like FreeIPA, which manages both Kerberos / key based authentication, information for that user would not be stored in `~/.ssh`, but rather in FreeIPA. Would this remediate that issue? As for the Kerberos token expiring, I am not as well versed in that, but I know there are some auto-renewal features out there. Not sure how well they would help with this particular problem.